# uninitialized constant DataShift::SpreeHelper::SpreeBaseLoader (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, spree, thor

Running Spree Commerce 2.2.

I'm attemptimg to run an extension called datashift_spree. It installed correctly, but won't execute

In my Gemfile:

gem 'datashift', github: 'autotelik/datashift'

gem 'datashift_spree', github: 'autotelik/datashift_spree'

When running
bundle exec thor datashift_spree:load:attach_images --input=/vagrant/imageimport/import.xls

I receive the error:
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/datashift_spree-0.5.0/lib/loaders/spree/image_loader.rb:19:in `<module:SpreeHelper>': uninitialized constant DataShift::SpreeHelper::SpreeBaseLoader (NameError)
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/datashift_spree-0.5.0/lib/loaders/spree/image_loader.rb:10:in`'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/datashift_spree-0.5.0/lib/loaders/spree/image_loader.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in`require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/datashift_spree-0.5.0/lib/thor/spree/products_images.thor:77:in`attach_images'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in`start'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/runner.rb:36:in `method_missing'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:29:in`run'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:126:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in`start'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/bin/thor:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/thor:23:in`load'
        from /usr/local/bin/thor:23:in `'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Code bug.
Can be fixed by applying the changes in this pull request:
https://github.com/autotelik/datashift_spree/pull/34